# Commodore 64 breadbin plastic stands repair options?

Tags: commodore-64, repair

I have a Commodore 64. The internal plastic stands for the board were all cracked and some were completely destroyed. See pictures

[image: Broken plastic stand]

In a futile attempt to fix them, I removed the old broken ones, sandpapered the area (a small hole remains, as in the old stand the screw went a bit through the case) and tried replacing them with a nylon stand, cutting it to length and attaching it with epoxy

[image: Nylon stand fix]

But the unfortunate reality is that epoxy has very little strength when torqued, and the stand inevitably detaches.

I tried 3D printing larger stands to ensure more surface (I have a resin 3D printer) but the tolerances are very small (the screw is a M3) and, most importantly, the resin is not very strong and glassy, and delaminates/snaps when the screw bites.

I am out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that either "8-bit Guy", or "Adrian's Digital basement" (I think the former) has a YT video where a C64 stand-off/screw mount is repaired - I vaguely remember seeing it. However, *which* video it was, or how it was done, I wouldn't be able to say, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm failing to understand how the plastic cases repair complies with 'computing' part of the 'retrocomputing' topic.

Comment: @lvd Dude, it's literally the first line of what is considered on-topic for this site: *Retrocomputing involves the restoration, preservation, history and maintenance of computer and gaming systems of yesteryear.*

Comment: Still the same. What a plastic case has to do with the "Computer"? This case does not compute per se nor helps the actual computer stuff to compute. Actually I'm afraid of a flood of questions that might arise from here: how to restore broken plastic, how to whiten the keycaps etc. In my opinion, while this relates to retro, it does not to computing.

Comment: @lvd - Post a meta question about it, so that the community can vote.

Comment: @lvd You're entitled to your opinion, of course, but I have to tell you it differs from the stated on-topic provisions in the help centre. Specifically the aforementioned first line, and more specifically the second line, which unequivocally puts (and tags) hardware maintenance and preservation within scope: *how to use or preserve computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer.*

Comment: We've had questions before about cleaning keyboards, 3d printed replacement this-and-that, etc. that were accepted and answered just fine.  You might as well say that a question about fixing a bad capacitor or an overheating box are off topic as well ... but they aren't.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly acceptable fit. It's about repairing a retro computer while trying to maintain it's originality. @OP - might be a plastic welding option might work, melting the base and printed stand together with a soldering iron or similar? Bit extreme maybe and I'd be hesitant if the machine is of personal nostalgic value, but might work well.

Answer (score 6):

Epoxy doesn’t adhere well to nylon but should be ok on the enclosure if you sandpaper the surface a little.  Remember that 5-minute epoxy doesn’t reach full strength for 24 hours.  A 3D print should be viable, print about a 2.5mm hole and then tap it to M3 - if you don’t have a tap then use an M3 screw; cut/grind off the thread down one side to create a cutting edge, or heat the screw a little to soften the printed material.

Comment: Actually, *nothing* does adhere well to nylon. It's just a poor choice of material to be glued.

Comment: \*nod* From what I remember, nylon and polypropylene are the two main plastics you're likely to encounter that don't react to solvents like acetone, and that's also why they don't glue well.

Comment: @ssokolow - and polyethylene, too.  AIUI you can use xylene, which some brands of paint thinners contain, to make a solvent weld.  There are probably people on the 3D printing stack exchange who could give more info on this, though, as I've never actually tried it.